# Maven Jar dependency is not coming automatically

Tags: java, maven

I am quite new to Maven.
I have a Maven Project.
When I create execute using mvn clean -e install it creates executable jar (commounutil.jar) for my project in target folder.
Not I have another project (project2) in Eclipse which is not a Maven based project.
Project2 uses features and classes from commounutil.jar.
If I manually add my executable jar commounutil.jar in eclipse using Java build path/add external jar.
But even after adding this jar there are some errors in my project which are related to log4j.
Now when I build commounutil the dependency for log4j was already added.
Still it is giving compile time error.
Could you please tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: It is not able to get class for log4j

Comment: Error is
The import org.apache cannot be resolved

Comment: upload your pom.xml and show your errors and give more details. Consider convert Project2 to maven project and include project1 as dependency if that is what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add log4j in your Eclipse classpath. Commonutils.jar,if it follows modularity promoted by maven,provides only common utils class and do not provide class related to its dependencies.

Maybe you should consider to update your second project to a maven project.

Comment: When I build my first project the dependency was already there. I wonder if dependency was already there then target jar created by project 1 should have that dependency included automaticall. Am I correct here?

Comment: The dep is in the maven repo, so not in the classpath. When you try to build the second project, Eclipse have only acces to the class available in the classpath.

Comment: We agree that you only have add the commonUtils.jar in the classpath. When you do this, the class present in the CommonUtils.jar are now available at compile time for your project build with Eclipse. Now, if you open this jar and inspect the class directories you will not find any .class related to log4j.

Comment: Converted project 2 as a maven project and added project 1 as dependency solved the problem. Thank a lot guys for the help :P